# Should I enable GZIP compression for WebP images?

Tags: node.js, express, web, gzip, webp

Is it still relevant to enable gzip compression after compressed the WebP images..?

In my case I use compression middleware for `express`.

Answer (score 7):

Yahoo suggests against it:

> Image and PDF files should not be gzipped because they are already compressed. Trying to gzip them not only wastes CPU but can potentially increase file sizes.

https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

And this may be helpful: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/gzipped-images-is-it-worth

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you update your answer or maybe @robertklep
Because the answer is kinda yes and no.

No because compressed images doesn't need to be gzipped. And Yes because I don't need to do anything else practically right now, because it is already (not) handled by the `compression` middleware.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it still relevant to enable gzip compression after compressed the WebP images..?

**Yes**.

The `compression` middleware never compressed images to begin with (by default), because most image formats already implement compression.

It only compresses responses for the following mime types:

- `text/*`
- `*/*+json`
- `*/*+text`
- `*/*+xml`

(and possibly other formats if their "compressibility" is known, see the [`compressible`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compressible) documentation for more details)

Converting images to WebP doesn't make a difference on how it works, and the abovementioned mime types are still good candidates to apply compression to.

Comment: Great answer! I guess my question kinda ambiguous.. It is yes and no.
No because compressed images doesn't need to be gzipped. And Yes because I don't need to do anything else practically right now, because it is already (not) handled by the middleware.

Comment: @AltianoGerung that's right. The default configuration for `compression` is smart enough to know which types of files/responses to (not) compress.